# How can I get major version updates with drush pm-update?

Tags: drush

I often check for updates to my modules using `drush pm-update`.  However, this check does not check for succeeding major versions.  For example, if I am using Mollom 1.1, `drush pm-update` will not alert me that there is a 2.3 version available as well.  Is there a way to tell drush to give me all possible updates, including major versions?

Comment: I did a quick check, and it doesn't seem there is a command for that. It would be possible to create a new command, or a Drush script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can explicitly ask Drush to tell you all of the available releases for a specific project using the pm-releases command:

```
$ drush pm-releases mollom
------- RELEASES FOR 'MOLLOM' PROJECT -------
 Release         Date         Status                 
 7.x-2.x-dev     2012-Dec-19  Development            
 7.x-2.3         2012-Oct-22  Supported, Recommended 
 7.x-1.x-dev     2011-Dec-20  Development            
 7.x-1.1         2011-Jul-09  Supported, Installed
```

However, what you want to do -- to have pm-update(code) automatically notify you when there is a newer major release -- is not supported.  I have opened a feature request in the Drush issue queue for you:  http://drupal.org/node/1880970

**UPDATE:**

Regarding kiamlaluno's comment, you can force the update using pm-download:

```
$ drush dl mollom-7.x-2.3
$ drush updatedb
```

I think that it would be more difficult to write a script to check for updates with pm-releases than it would be to enhance pm-updatecode to show this information.  If you'd like to help out, please post a patch at the issue I linked to above.

Comment: Thanks, it's good to know that this feature doesn't currently exist rather than I'm just using Drush wrong.